# Getting SQL server exception when executing connection java file through ant build.xml file

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, sql-server-2008, ant

- I have Java file to connect to SQL server database and retrieve data from it.
- When I execute this java file from eclipse it successfully connects to database and retrieve data from DB.
- But when I call same java file from ant build.xml file, its throwing SQL server exception while creating connection object.

Not able to get what may be the issue. Please help!!

Sql exception thrown: -

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host 10.6.1.67, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute(ExecuteJava.java:194)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.run(Java.java:771)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:221)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:36)
     [java]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:452)
     [java]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:139)
```

Below is my java file code:-

```
    package util;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;

    public class JavaSQLConnection{ 
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String connectionUrl="jdbc:sqlserver://10.6.1.67";
            String port="1433";
            String databaseName="Microsoft";
            String user="selenium";
            String password="password123";
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+":"+port+";databaseName="+databaseName+";user="+user+";password="+password);

            String Sql = "select name, address, url from School where schoolid=?";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
            ResultSet rs = null;
            stmt.setInt(1, 875632);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()){
                System.out.println(rs.getString("url"));
            }
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

This is how I have created ant build.xml:(I execute ant target **run**)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
]>

<project name="Sample" basedir=".">

    <property environment="env" />
    <property name="proj.home" value="${basedir}" />
    <property name="lib.location" value="${proj.home}/lib" />
    <property name="build.location" value="${proj.home}/build" />
    <property name="classes.location" value="${build.location}\compiledclasses" />
    <property name="src.location" value="${proj.home}/src" />


    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.location}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>


    <target name="clean">
        <delete failonerror="false" dir="${build.location}" />
    </target>   


    <!-- compile -->
    <target name="compile" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.location}" />
        <mkdir dir="${classes.location}" />
        <javac includeantruntime="true" srcdir="${src.location}" destdir="${classes.location}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>


    <!-- run -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <java classname="util.JavaSQLConnection" classpath="${classes.location}" classpathref="classpath" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: If all says in the exception only. Check if the server is running on the given IP. check the IP and the port. And do a ping test between the two machines to see if the connection is working. Other than that then, there is no problem in the code that I can see.

Comment: Are multiple launches direct in eclipse sucessful or only the first launch? Runs ant the same java version as the launch in eclipse?